# Add item then assign value for that item in list

Tags: c#-4.0

I am using one object list type where it read data from datareader and add in the list.
Below is the code for the same:

```
 public static List<object[]> LoadRecordsFromDataReaderToList(SqlDataReader reader, int dataLimit)
 {
      List<object[]> dataList = new List<object[]>();
      while (reader.Read())
      {
          object[] columnName = new object[reader.FieldCount];
          for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
          {
              columnName[i] = reader.GetName(i);
          }
          dataList = new List<object[]>{columnName};
          object[] tempRow = new object[reader.FieldCount];
          for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
          {
              tempRow[i] = reader[i];
          }

          dataList.Add(tempRow);
      }
      return dataList;
  }
```

As you can see in above code first running one for loop to get all the columns and assign in list like below image.
[List with column name image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcnNl.png)

Then running one more loop to get the value and trying to assign for the same column name but after added tempRow list is showing two items count, First items with all the column names and second items with all the values.
Below is the image added for all the values.
[List with added values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cQ5N.png)

How do i assign value for the specific column index in list?
Please let me know if you have any concerns.

Comment: The `while` is the first loop which iterates every record in the reader. There you always add all column names

Comment: @TimSchmelter, Could you please correct me what i am doing wrong there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to add the column-names as "header" once and not always in the while-loop.
You are always overwriting the whole list in the record-loop at:

```
dataList = new List<object[]>{columnName};
```

I think you can use this approach:

```
public static List<object[]> LoadRecordsFromDataReaderToList(SqlDataReader reader)
{
    List<object[]> dataList = new List<object[]>();

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        // add header first and just once
        string[] columns = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount)
            .Select(reader.GetName)
            .ToArray();
        dataList.Add(columns);
    }

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // add data records
        object[] tempRow = new object[reader.FieldCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            tempRow[i] = reader[i];
        }
        dataList.Add(tempRow);
    }
    return dataList;
}
```

Comment: I have checked given code but still i can see after added temprow in datalist i have two item count. One is string count for columns and second is object count for values. I need here for every column item should have their value as well. Like how we use List<Report_UserDetails> userDetailsList = new List<Report_UserDetails>(); where Report_UserDetails object we have properies name. When add value to this list value is getting set for particular property. Hope you understand what i am trying to say.

Comment: Tim, It is working now. I was doing some mistakes while implementing above code.